# Can this be accomplished by a Graph Database?

Tags: neo4j

I have a request to develop an application that keep track of the movements of a certain item (or items). To better demonstrate what the application must do, I drew a [diagram (simplified abstraction)](http://www.4shared.com/photo/DeMZMB9_/all-senarios.html).

As I never worked with any databases other than the relational ones, I really don't know if I can solve this problem with a graph database.

These questions must be answered by the system:

1. What was the path that a certain pen drive walked?
2. I passed some pen drivers. Where are they now?
3. What are the pens I received, from where did they come from and to where did they go?
4. Where are the pens I burned and passed? And with whom?

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Neo4j everything is either a node or a relationship. So it's useful to think: what would be my nodes and relationships?

Here it might be, for example, that every "pen drive, "person" and "location" is a node. Verbs like "walk" or "give" would be your relationships.

In this model, you'd be able use "Cypher" to query for things like "give me all location nodes connected to pen nodes by the relationship walk." Or, say "start at all person nodes and return nodes who have a give relationship to a pen drive node that doesn't have a give relationship that connects back to the starting person node."

This rich graph query language gives you nice algorithms like shortest distance for free, so you beyond a transactional record you could determine whether, for example, a pen drive made it from A to B using the optimal path. But as you can see above, "relational joins" do not beget simple queries or descriptions thereof.

When it comes to database design, when the model becomes cumbersome to map mentally, it's going to be a pain to develop too. Design your database based on how you plan to query it. If you're unable to easily explain those queries in terms of Neo4j, it's possible that Neo4j isn't going to be the best fit.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, editor. It seems to me that I need to play with this a little. I will install Neo4j and try to simulate the diagram I drew. As you said, if I found too difficult to accomplish what I need, then I am in the wrong path.

Comment: You can even use http://gist.neo4j.org to sketch that online and try (and document) some queries, without the need to install neo4j.

Comment: This is really nice, Peter. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Not bad when you get Neo4j tips from the creator of Neo4j! But should I be offended by the non-upvote? ;)

Comment: No, you shouldn't, editor. The thing is I don't have enough reputation to vote.